# PowerApps Flow: Action Failed on Condition

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I am getting this error message:

`InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Condition' at line '1' and column '3364': 'The template language expression 'body('Get_item')['EmployeeLoginID']' cannot be evaluated because property 'EmployeeLoginID' doesn't exist, available properties are 'value'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.`

[image]

this has happened after I added several conditions to my "Apply to each" .

**My current flow:**
[image]
The two conditions here are "Employee_PrimaryLoginID" and "EmployeeID"

This is particularly strange as I didnt have this error before, then after appending so more conditions beneath this condition I am getting this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens sometimes when you introduce new connectors to a flow after you have initially saved the flow without using that connector.

**You can choose the following solutions：**

1.Recreating new flow from scratch solve the issue.

2.Go to the Power Automate, export your flow. Then, Import your flow ( as a new flow).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[Unable to process template language expressions in Custom Connector](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/property-shared-office365-doesn-t-exist/m-p/129840#M12737)

Comment: On import, is there anything in particular i am looking to change? I tried export and importing and still same error :( . I "Created as new" instead of overwriting.

Comment: Hi Jonnyboi. We recommended that you create a new Microsoft Flow to replace it. And delete the error Microsoft Flow.

Answer (score 1):

The issue sometimes occurres when the field value is null on CRM. Because of that the Dataverse connector didn't return the field name in the output so when trying to get the value of the field it returned the above error.

An alternative solution for this issue is to check if the field exists before getting its value, like this :

```
if (contains(body('Get_item'),'EmployeeLoginID') , body('Get_item')['EmployeeLoginID'],'')
```